# How to fix Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I'm trying to launch a new windows xp virtual machine, but, when I do, I get this error message:

> Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITABLE).
>
> Code d'erreur : NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Composant : Console
>   Interface : IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJXKW.png]

How do I to fix it, please?

Comment: Switch to KVM / Virt manager. Does not require 3rd party stuff ;)

Comment: try `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` and then try running the VM again.

Comment: @sмurf, I've got this as result `sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found`.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, I think that I need to complety remove all the config files of virtualbox. Because, when I try to reinstall virtualbox, I get the same error on launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this in the IRC:

the file permissions on nearly all / folders are a mess (nearly all have 777).
a

```
sudo chmod o-w /usr
```

did fix it.

But i strongly suggest a reinstall since there is no way to get the permissions right again for all folders and files.